# Android studio Bottom navigation bar: How do I set the middle button to be clicked first?

Tags: java, android-studio

Currently, when I open the app, the left most button is initially clicked.
How do I change it so that the middle button is initially clicked when the app is run.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tow way to define default fragment :

**1st :** Set the selected index `setSelectedItemId`

`bottomNavigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.item_id);`

---

**2nd :** Also you can create `PushFragment` method like below :

```
public void PushFragment(Fragment fragment){

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_Frame, fragment).addToBackStack( "HomeFragment" ).commit();
    }
```

And in `onCreate()` method declare `PushFragment()` with your default fragment id see below code :

```
PushFragment(new HomeFragment());
```

Comment: But with your second method, bottom navigation selected item will still be the first one, although fragment that is shown is second

Comment: i can use this method it's work for me batter @VivekMishra

Answer (score 0):

How you are loading bottom navigation bar items dynamically or static???

static means use like this:

`bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.your_middle_item_id);`